Removing a Mistakenly Added Device from Device Manager
I was trying to install Waves MaxxAudio Pro on an unsupported Realtek audio card. I have tried to install a supported driver to my unsupported hardware, but as expected it did not install.
So, stupidly enough, I have opened the driver's folder and right-clicked a couple of .inf files and installed them, hoping that this would allow Waves to work. It did not work eventually, but the problem is that now I have an extra audio device appearing in my Device Manager that doesn't exit in my device.
What I have tried:

Right-clicking the device and uninstall. But, it appears again when
the list is refreshed.
Disabled the device (as seen in the screened image).
Running pnputil to uninstall all the .inf files I have installed.
(Where <example.inf> is replaced by the name of each .inf file)

C:\Windows\INF>pnputil /delete-driver <example.inf> /uninstall
I know that this is such a stupid thing to do, but is there a tool to    use to completely remove the device?
https://ibb.co/NjLnDPk
##EDIT
For those who might make the same mistake, here is a simple script I made to uninstall all .inf files that are contained in a driver's folder and subfolders. Just edit the path to the driver's extracted folder where the .inf files are present: "DRIVER_DIR=", save it as a .bat then browse to where you saved the .bat script using an Admin's cmd and run the script. A log file will be generated showing all the drivers uninstalled.
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Set the directory containing the .inf files
set "DRIVER_DIR=C:\Users\MG\Desktop\FORCED"

:: Set the log file name
set "LOG_FILE=ME_Uninstall_Log.txt"

:: Loop through all .inf files in the directory and its subdirectories
for /R "%DRIVER_DIR%" %%f in (*.inf) do (
    echo Uninstalling driver: %%~nxf >> %LOG_FILE%
    set "COMMAND=pnputil /delete-driver "%%~ff" /uninstall /force"
    echo Executing command: !COMMAND! >> %LOG_FILE%
    call !COMMAND! >> %LOG_FILE% 2>&1
)

echo All drivers have been uninstalled. >> %LOG_FILE%
echo Log file is located at %LOG_FILE%
pause


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

For those who might make the same mistake, here is a simple script I made to uninstall all .inf files that are contained in a driver's folder and subfolders. Just edit the path to the driver's extracted folder where the .inf files are present: "DRIVER_DIR=", save it as a .bat then browse to where you saved the .bat script using an Admin's cmd and run the script. A log file will be generated showing all the drivers uninstalled.
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Set the directory containing the .inf files
set "DRIVER_DIR=C:\Users\MG\Desktop\FORCED"

:: Set the log file name
set "LOG_FILE=ME_Uninstall_Log.txt"

:: Loop through all .inf files in the directory and its subdirectories
for /R "%DRIVER_DIR%" %%f in (*.inf) do (
    echo Uninstalling driver: %%~nxf >> %LOG_FILE%
    set "COMMAND=pnputil /delete-driver "%%~ff" /uninstall /force"
    echo Executing command: !COMMAND! >> %LOG_FILE%
    call !COMMAND! >> %LOG_FILE% 2>&1
)

echo All drivers have been uninstalled. >> %LOG_FILE%
echo Log file is located at %LOG_FILE%
pause

